# Не могу получить указатель на функцию

Tags: c#, winapi

Пытаюсь получить указатель через GetProcAddress, но не получаю, выводит ошибку:
Ptr NullException
Хотя функция СreateFileA есть

```
delegate IntPtr CreateFileADelegate(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
public static void Test()
{
   IntPtr loadLibrary = LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll");
   IntPtr createFileA = GetProcAddress(loadLibrary, "CreateFileA");
   if (createFileA != IntPtr.Zero)
   {
      CreateFileADelegate createFile = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<CreateFileADelegate>(createFileA);
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Не удалось получить указатель на функцию");
   }
}
```

Comment: Что такое LoadLibrary? GetProcAddress? Про маршаллинг слышали? Кто вам сказал, что `lpFileNane` это `string`? Без маршаллинга вы не можете использовать управляемые типы в аргументах.

Comment: Кстати, вместо того, чтобы генерить костыли, попробуйте .NET 7 и `LibraryImport` вместо `DllImport` и посмотрите, какой код генерируется для маршаллинга. Кажется то, что вы пытаетесь реализовать, уже реализовано разработчиками .NET. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke-source-generation